# CASE expression syntax error SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, syntax

I have researched everywhere but still can't seem to fix a simple error:
Running Microsoft SQL server:

```
UPDATE copyprogmaster
       SET active =
                 CASE
                   WHEN active = 1 THEN active = 0
                   WHEN active = 0 THEN active = 1
                  ELSE active
                 END
WHERE source = 'Mass_Mail'
```

my error is :

> Line 4: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `=` after the `THEN`, so:

```
  UPDATE copyprogmaster
       SET active =
                 CASE
                   WHEN active = 1 THEN 0
                   WHEN active = 0 THEN 1
                  ELSE active
                 END
  WHERE source = 'Mass_Mail'
```

You already have `active =` after the `SET` on the second line.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to repeat "active =" after THEN

```
UPDATE copyprogmaster
       SET active =
                 CASE
                   WHEN active = 1 THEN 0
                   WHEN active = 0 THEN 1
                  ELSE active
                 END
WHERE source = 'Mass_Mail'
```

Here's an example from the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END,
   Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your query, I assume the `active` field is `bit` or `int` (assuming that `int` field has only values **0**, **1**, or **NULL**). In that case, I believe that you can write the query as following:

```
UPDATE  dbo.copyprogmaster
SET     active = active ^ 1
WHERE   source = 'Mass_Mail'
```

Notice that the query can handle `NULL` values and also the rows #**1**, #**4** and #**6** in the screenshot are unchanged. Screenshot #**1** shows table structure and screenshot #**2** displays sample execution of the above query.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: Table]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: Output]